# Install Ubuntu 13.04 on Macbook 17"

Tags: installation, 13.04, radeon, macbook

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 13.04 on a 17" macbook pro and running into some issues that I believe are related to the video card (Radeon HD 6700M).

The steps took are: I download the 13.04 AMD64+MAC iso and make a bootable usb drive. I then boot off of the usb stick, select "Try Ubuntu without installing" and the screen then goes black and never recovers.

If I edit the boot parameters and add the nomodeset parameter Ubuntu boots to command line. Running startx at that point errors out saying that there are no screens available.

If I edit the boot parameters and add the radeon.modeset=0 parameter Ubuntu boots to command line again, but will then launch a GUI telling me that it is in low graphics mode. No matter which option I select from this dialog the dialog with vanish and I will be left at the command prompt.

I have also tried using the server install disk, with the same results (This actually confused me as I expected a CLI install).

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can get Ubuntu installed on my Mac? As much as I would like a full UI I would setting for just being able to install a command line version.

Answer (score 0):

I found a guide that might help you:

http://tech.deepumohan.com/2012/04/ati-radeon-hd-6600m-graphics-card-on.html

If you are confident on doing an command line installation, there is hope for you. You can use the Minimal CD image to do a text based installation:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Then after booting your freshly installed system:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
sudo aticonfig --initial --input=/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Restart your system and when it is back up:

```
fglrxinfo 
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

Comment: mqor, Thanks for the response. The issue I have with the MinimalCD is that it doesn't support booting from UEFI systems, which Macs are (with no bios support to speak of). So unfortunately I cannot install the CLI using the minimal cd.

I will look at the guide you provided when I am home and can see if I can execute the steps off the live cd's CLI.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on my Macbook Air this Saturday, using the normal 64-bit installation image. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting. I however had to convert it to legacy/BIOS mode after the installation since the proprietary nvidia drivers (GeForce 320M) doesn't work in EFI-mode.